# Access specific properties of an object contained within a List<Object> in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I can't seem to figure out how to access specific properties of each object contained within a list. For example, if I reference the object outside of the list (prior to passing it to the button click), I can see properties like "tag", "height", "width", etc. (all the standard properties for that type). However, I cannot figure out how to access those object-specific properties once the list has been passed to my button click event.

Please refer to this example:

```
private TextBox createTextBox(string name)
{
    // Create TextBox Code is Here
    TextBox dTextBox = new TextBox();
    dTextBox.Name = name;
    dTextBox.Tag = "sometag";
    dTextBox.Height = 12345;
    dTextBox.Width = 12345;
    return dTextBox;
}

private void some_function()
{
    var objectList = new List<Object>();
    objectList.Add(createTextBox("example1"));
    objectList.Add(createTextBox("example2"));
    objectList.Add(createTextBox("example3"));
}

private int button_click(object sender, EventArgs e, Int32 ticketGroupID, List<Object> objectList)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < objectList.Count(); i++)
    {
        Int32 valuableInfo = objectList[i].?? // Here is where I am trying to access specific properties about the object at index i in the list, such as the objects TAG, VALUE, etc. How can this be done?
        // do things with the valuable info
    };

}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: If all the object you are storing in your list are the same type change your list declaration to that type: `new List<TextBox>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `object` strongly-typed. That is, to cast it to your `class`:

```
Int32 valuableInfo = ((TextBox)objectList[i]).Height; //now you can access your property
```

Otherwise, you cannot access the properties of the class because the compiler wouldn't know what is the actual type of the `object`. Also, your Intellisense will just deemed it as `object`, not your strongly-typed class (example: `MyClass`, or in your case, the class being `TextBox`)

Comment: My list can contain various types of controls at once. Is it possible to determine which control it is. Like a textbox, vs a combobox for the specific index?

Comment: ah, yes, possible. please use keyword `as`. Or, more generally, you could always cast your `object` to the parent `class` `Control`. As long as your properties are in the parent class `Control`, any `Control` (be it `TextBox`, `CheckBox`, etc) will have their properties accessible by you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [List<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which implements [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), so you can make use of the [`OfType<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to extract items that are already strongly typed and ready for you to access:

```
var myListOfTypedObjects = myList.OfType<TextBox>();
myListOfTypedObjects.ForEach(tb => Console.Writeline(tb.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either check `type` first, then cast it to `TextBox` later or *reverse*.

See example below:

```
foreach (var obj in objectList)
{
    // method 1: check first, cast later
    if (obj is TextBox)
    {
        Int32 valueableInfo = ((TextBox)obj).Height;
    }

    // method2: cast first, check later
    var textBox = obj as TextBox;
    if (obj != null)
    {
        Int32 valueableInfo = obj.Height;
    }
}
```